# How to update an arbitrary field in a POJO?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jdo

I have a POJO called MyClass.
MyClass has a 100 getters and setters (for example)

I create two instances. Instance A and Instance B.

A user somehow changes the value of any arbitrary field on Instance B.

Is there a way or shortcut I can compare Instance A and Instance B such that I can update the change in value to Instance A?

**UPDATED** Okay just to clarify some confusion.

Let's just say

Instance A = An instance of MyClass which represents an existing record persisted via JDO on the server-side. MyClass has an instance variable of foo="bar0";

Instance B = An instance of MyClass which a user has edited any arbitrary field, i.e. foo="bar1". Instance B comes from data supplied by an Android client.

So it could be any instance variable on MyClass that could be in Instance B which represents how Instance A should be updated.

Comment: why not just make that variable static?

Comment: The real question here is why you have 100 members in a single POJO.  Maybe your POJO should wrap a Map of properties, which you could then easily compare to find the differences.

Comment: 100 members was just to exaggerate the example.

Comment: How are these objects instantiated? Why are there two objects - one representing the in-database data and another representing the edited data? Are they separated by a network?

Comment: Yes, they are separated by a network. There are two objects because Instance A is a reference to the existing persisted version and Instance B is a copy with some fields updated. This is to execute an update transaction. Create, Delete, and Reads have been easy. The Update not so trivial.

Comment: Can you provide more information behind the motivation for this problem? Depending on what you are using for persistence, there might be an existing mechanism for doing the "Diff". 

It seems to me that you want the server to get an object from the client, do a DIFF to see what fields have changed compared to the server's cached copy, then update the backing persistence using that DIFF. I can see this becoming troublesome when you have multiple clients sending results to the server -- have you considered race conditions and contention resolution?

Comment: I am using Google App Engine's JDO 2.3 for persistence. Yes, a diff is what I want to do.

Answer (score 1):

Use a [Unit Of Work](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/unitOfWork.html). A Unit Of Work is used to determine which entities/objects are "dirty"  - meaning their in-memory data is out-of-sync with the persistence store or database - and which are "clean".

Just tweak the concept to keep track of which properties are dirty and you're good to go.

## Example

(it's been a while since I've written Java and I don't have Java on this machine, so there might be little errors)

### `MyClass.java`

```
public class MyClass extends ChangeObservable {

    private String name;
    private Age int;

    public MyClass(name, age) {
        // when the object is first created,
        // I'm assuming that the "clean" values are provided
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }

    public String getName() { return name; }
    public void setName(n) {
        name = n;
        this.fireChangeEvent("name");
    }
    public String getAge() { return age; }
    public void setAge(a) {
        age = a;
        this.fireChangeEvent("age");
    }

}
```

### `UnitOfWork.java`

```
public class UnitOfWork implements ChangeListener {    

    // dunno if this is the most efficient implementation...
    private HashSet<String> dirties = new HashSet<String>();
    private Observable obj;

    public UnitOfWork(Observable obj) {
        this.obj = obj;
        obj.registerChangeListener(this);
    }

    public void registerDirty(propName) {
        // probably more code needed...
        dirties.add(propName);
    }

   public HashSet<String> getDirtyProperties() {
        // probably more code needed...
       return new HashSet<String>(dirties);
   }

   public void onChangeEvent(propName) {
       this.registerDirty(propName);
   }

    // note: a UnitOfWork needs more functionality than this!
    // I've implemented the bare minimum for the example
    // but it would also need methods like `registerClean(...)`

}
```

### `Driver.java`

```
public class MyDriver {

    public static void main(String[] argv) {
        MyClass myObj = new MyClass("Richard", 3);
        UnitOfWork uow = new UnitOfWork(myObj);
        myObj.setName("Mark");
        for(String propName : uow.getDirtyProperties()) {
            System.out.print(propName);
        }
    }

}
```

... now the `UnitOfWork.getDirtyProperties(...)` can be used to determine which properties are clean and dirty.

Answer (score 0):

**DISCLAIMER**: I am a fan of Guice, but **IT. IS. AWESOME.**

This sounds like a problem of shared state. State should not be static, you should probably be using GUICE to manage a singleton instance of A. (not sure why you need A and B)

Anyways, if you want to be fancy and intercept the `A.setFoo`, you should look at the [AOP support in GUICE.](http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/AOP)

Comment: Is that supposed to be a link?

Comment: Yeah, guice would be ideal if this wasn't an issue about persistence. Please see my recent edits to the question above.

Answer (score 0):

Just don't agree, in your case you don't need AOP, but you need Introspection.

Are you using Spring? If that's the case the BeanWrapperImpl class is a very good start, you define a bean wrapper around A and a bean wrapper around B. Then easily iterate over its properties, and copy values from one to another.

If you don't want to do that Apache Commons BeanUtils provides the same functionality.

Answer (score -1):

You can either use Aspect oriented programming (using something like [AspectJ](http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/)), or you could write a solution using reflection which will compare the properties of one object to another.

Comment: I recommend using introspection instead of reflection. Because it is a Java Bean.